# Using Picasso to Load Images in List Crashes app on Scroll

Tags: android, android-listview, picasso

I've been using `Picasso` to populate a `listview` with URLs that return images. The URLs are returned from a API call.

Adapter

```
public class RecipeAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements ListAdapter {


    private final Activity activity;
    private final JSONArray jsonArray;


    public RecipeAdapter (Activity activity, JSONArray jsonArray){
        assert activity !=null;
        assert jsonArray != null;

        this.jsonArray = jsonArray;
        this.activity = activity;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount(){
        if(null==jsonArray)
            return 0;
        else
            return jsonArray.length();
    }

    @Override
    public JSONObject getItem(int position){
        if(null==jsonArray) return null;
        else
            return jsonArray.optJSONObject(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position){

        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView (int position, View v, ViewGroup parent){
        if (v == null) {
            v = View.inflate(activity, R.layout.recipe_item, null);
        }

        CircularImageView icon = (CircularImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.recipeIcon);
        TextView title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.recipeTitle);
        TextView supplier = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.supplier);


        JSONObject JSdata = getItem(position);
        if(null!=JSdata){
            try {
                if (JSdata.has("title")) {
                    title.setText(JSdata.getString("title"));
                }
                if (JSdata.has("publisher")) {
                    supplier.setText(JSdata.getString("publisher"));
                }
                if (JSdata.has("image_url")) {
                    String image = JSdata.getString("image_url");

                    String[] imagearray = image.split("\\.");
                    String extension = imagearray[imagearray.length - 1];

                    String tag = new String();

                    if (extension.equals("jpg")) {
                        if (URLUtil.isValidUrl(image)) {
                            Picasso.with(activity)
                                    .load(image)
                                    .centerCrop()
                                    .tag(tag)
                                    .error(R.drawable.icon01)
                                    .resize(50, 50)
                                    .into(icon);

                        } else {
                            Picasso.with(activity)
                                    .load(R.drawable.icon01)
                                    .centerCrop()
                                    .resize(50, 50)
                                    .tag(tag)
                                    .into(icon);

                        }

                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {

                Toast.makeText(activity, "Error finding recipes",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
       final ImageView fav = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.favbutton);
        fav.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                fav.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_white_24dp);
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Added to favourites",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        return v;
    }


}
```

I've done a lot of reading about this, and I've attempted to use the `.tag()` method and a scroll listener:

```
  class Populate extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONArray> {

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progress = ProgressDialog.show(RecipeSearch.this, "Finding Recipes", "Searching....", true);
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONArray doInBackground(String... urls) {
        JSONParser recipeParse = new JSONParser();
        String rawJSON = recipeParse.getJSON(urls[0]);

        try {

            if (rawJSON != null) {
                JSONObject object = new JSONObject(rawJSON);
                JSONArray jArray = object.getJSONArray("recipes");
                return jArray;
            } else {
                JSONArray jArray = null;
                return jArray;
            }

        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error Searching for Recipes",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

         JSONArray jArray = null;
            return jArray;
        }
        //do http request and add objects to array here.
        //need to do a custom adapter
       // return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray jArray) {

        if (jArray != null) {
            final ListView recipes = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.recipeView);

            recipes.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    JSONObject selected = (JSONObject) (recipes.getItemAtPosition(position));

                    String url = null;
                    try {
                        url = selected.getString("source_url");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                    startActivity(i);

                }
            });
           final String tag ="";
            recipes.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
                @Override
                public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {


                    Picasso picasso = Picasso.with(getApplicationContext());
                    if (scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE ||
                            scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL) {
                        picasso.resumeTag(tag);
                    } else {
                        picasso.pauseTag(tag);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

                    Picasso picasso = Picasso.with(getApplicationContext());
                    picasso.pauseTag(tag);
                }
            });

            recipeAdapter = new RecipeAdapter(RecipeSearch.this, jArray);//jArray is your json array
            recipes.setAdapter(recipeAdapter);

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Recipes Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }



        progress.dismiss();
    }
}
```

I though this might solve the problem, but when I scroll on large lists, it causes the app to crash. LogCat:

```
   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference
            at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:591)
            at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.refreshBitmapShader(CircularImageView.java:341)
            at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.invalidate(CircularImageView.java:262)
            at android.widget.ImageView.setImageDrawable(ImageView.java:456)
            at com.squareup.picasso.PicassoDrawable.setPlaceholder(PicassoDrawable.java:61)
            at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into(RequestCreator.java:664)
            at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into(RequestCreator.java:601)
            at io.moffat.kitchenpal.RecipeAdapter.getView(RecipeAdapter.java:99)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2347)
            at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1864)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillUp(ListView.java:732)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:671)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:4991)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.scrollIfNeeded(AbsListView.java:3418)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchMove(AbsListView.java:3801)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3632)
            at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8471)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2399)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2092)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2405)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2405)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2405)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2405)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2405)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2405)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2369)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1719)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2742)
            at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:59)
            at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:59)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2330)
            at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8666)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4123)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3989)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3544)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3597)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3563)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3680)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3571)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3737)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3544)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3597)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3563)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3571)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3544)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent
```

Any help or suggestions would be welcomed

Comment: `com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.refreshBitmapShader(CircularImageView.java:341)` is this your class?

Comment: It's a library that creates a circular imageview, extends imageview class

Comment: The crash is happening inside that library; I guess your options are to investigate and submit a fix, to replace with an alternate library, or to implement your own circular image view.

Comment: Based on debugging it, I would assume it's because Picasso isn't returning the image quick enough for it to load. It works on smaller lists, it's just large ones that this problem arises with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of debugging, figured this out.

The library I was using was attempting to use methods upon the `CircularImageView` resource when it hadn't loaded properly. Changed to a different library and it's now working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with CircularImageView, image URLs, and Picasso. The 
issue lies within CircularImageView being loaded a placeholder image then your requested one. I solved it by using `noPlaceholder()` in my Picasso query.

You should be able to fix the above code by adding `noPlaceholder()` like so

```
if (URLUtil.isValidUrl(image)) {
    Picasso.with(activity)
        .load(image)
        .centerCrop()
        .tag(tag)
        .error(R.drawable.icon01)
        .resize(50, 50)
        .noPlaceholder()
        .into(icon);

} else {
     Picasso.with(activity)
         .load(R.drawable.icon01)
         .centerCrop()
         .resize(50, 50)
         .tag(tag)
         .noPlaceholder()
         .into(icon);
}
```

The issue is detailed in the Picasso Github https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/931